# Отправляется пустой инпут в базу данных

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, form

Есть форма:

```html
<form action="" method="POST" id="trade_form">
        <input type="text" class="set_input" name="set_input" >
 <input type="text" class="get_input" name="get_input" >
 <textarea class="write_comment left" name="comment" placeholder="Ваш комментарий к обмену:"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" name="enter" class="right" value="Создать обмен" />
</form>
```

Есть простейший скрипт, который заполняет эту форму данными:

```
$(".inv_item").click(function(event){
        $(".set_input").append( $(this).children("p").html() );
});
```

При клике фаербаг показывает, что эти значения попали в инпут, но когда я их отправляю в базу, то туда приходит пустая строка. Как это можно исправить ?

Comment: Ещё хочу отметить, что физически строка не попадает в инпут, то есть никаких надписей не появляется, но фаербаг показывает, что они там есть.

Comment: И если в инпут что-то написать, до данные нормлаьно отправляются.

Comment: у input нет метода append это же элемент формы, input можно заполнить так $(".set_input").val('some text');

Comment: @sepgg Точно ! Работает. Запишите в ответы, я галочку поставлю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> у input нет метода append это же элемент формы, input можно заполнить
>   так $(".set_input").val('some text');

[@sepgg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/33208/sepgg)